# convert Oracle DATE to linux time

Tags: linux, perl, oracle11g

I'm having trouble converting an Oracle DATE field to a linux time format in perl. 
I'm pulling the date field like this:

```
my $query = "SELECT RESPONSE_DATE FROM TABLENAME";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute() or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $sth->errstr;
my @results = $sth->fetchrow_array();
printf "response_date=%s",$results[0];
printf "localtime(time)=%s",localtime(time);
```

Output:

```
response_date=14-OCT-14 08.35.00.000000 PM
localtime(time)=Tue Aug 18 23:35:13 2015
```

I can get all the pieces of the local time like this:

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime(time);
```

But now I need to compare those pieces with similar pieces of response_date.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you need all the `localtime` fields for some sort of date calculation?

The [`Time::Piece`](http://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) module is the usual solution to this. It allows you to parse your database time and also overloads `localtime` to that it returns a `Time::Piece` object in scalar context

Unfortunately `Time::Piece` won't parse the fractional seconds field, so if it's not always zero then you will need to remove it from the date-time string

Clearly other calculations are possible once you have both the database value and the current date as `Time::Piece` objects

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

my $s = '14-OCT-14 08.35.00.000000 PM';

my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($s, '%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.000000 %p');

my $now = localtime;

printf "%s was %.3f days ago\n",
        $dt->strftime('%a %d-%b-%Y at %H:%M:%S'),
        ($now - $dt)->days;
```

#### output

```
Tue 14-Oct-2014 at 20:35:00 was 308.190 days ago
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't sure how to deal with the microseconds

Comment: @user3217883: If they're always zeroes then just put them in the format string. If not then remove them first with `$s =~ s/.*\K\.\d+//a`. Or you can probably tell Oracle what format to use for the date-time string

Comment: Thanks Borodin.  You did in one line what took me 5 using a combination of length, rindex, and substr!